# Giving criteria in namespace:: xpath function xslt

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to copy all the xsl namespace of a document to the root document with this code:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="//namespace::*[not(xxx:*)]" />
```

this works perfectly fine. However I don't want namespace `xxx` to be copied as given in the expression, however thats not happening. Even `xxx` is being copied along with other namespaces. I want to prevent `xxx` being copied. How to do that?

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to exclude namespaces with a given prefix, then do this

```
<xsl:copy-of select="//namespace::*[name() != 'xxx']" />
```

Howeverm if you wanted to exclude namespaces with a given namespace uri, then do this

```
<xsl:copy-of select="//namespace::*[. != 'xxx']" />
```

Comment: Also: you need to be aware that just because you don't copy a namespace explicitly doesn't mean that it won't be copied implicitly, for example because the namespace is actually used in the name of an element.